# In C++11 and later, is it still optimal to do an "empty" check before a "range for"?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, stl, iterator

I'm currently updating some older C++ code that I have that iterates over STL container types, and I'm finding a lot of code like this:

```
if (!edgeSet.empty())
{
  for(typename EdgeSet::const_iterator iter = edgeSet.begin(); iter != edgeSet.end(); iter++)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Which I am turning (successfully) into the equivalent:

```
if (!edgeSet.empty())
{
  for(auto& edge : edgeSet)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

And I was wondering... is the "`empty`" check necessary for a "range for"? I would imagine it would be necessary in the older "iterator style" for loop to avoid a useless initialization and comparison / branch, but I'm curious if a "range for" automatically does an empty check or not before it even starts.

Further, if the optimization does happen, does it happen at all optimization levels (including no optimization: `-O0` )?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't imagine it was ever necessary, unless you had some custom class returning an expensive iterator

Comment: I don't see how it prevents a useless comparison since you are already doing a comparison.

Comment: I believe you've stumbled over an old cargo cult. There's no need to keep performing its rituals.

Comment: @molbdnilo , you're correct of course, this was something I hadn't originally kept in mind. I don't necessarily get to work with C++ in my day-to-day and I think my mindset is not in assuming "zero overhead abstraction" are a given. (Or at least that's the excuse I'll stick with for now.)

Comment: @Tas , right-- I hadn't investigated how expensive (or inexpensive) the iterators or `empty` methods are for STL containers. I think on the whole I could have assumed STL was going to be as optimal as one could get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `empty()` function checks if the container has no elements, i.e. whether `begin() == end()` and returns `true` if container is empty.

The [range-based `for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop produces code equivalent to the following

```
{
  auto && __range = range_expression ; 
  for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; 
  __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
    range_declaration = *__begin; 
    loop_statement 
  } 
}
```

The controlling expression in the `for` loop is `is __begin != __end`. 
You can see the check in `empty()`  and the check here are equivalent.
So there is **no need** for an additional `empty()` check before using the range-based `for` loop.

Comment: The fact that `empty()` is equivalent to `begin() == end()` doesn't mean it has to be implemented like that for all containers. If a container keeps a `size` data member, and has expensive iterators, then it would make more sense to do `size() == 0`.

Comment: Yes, but I was going with the `empty()` defined for `std::set` (which the OP is using) which makes that check. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/empty

Comment: OP is talking about "STL containers", not `std::set` specifically. Also the reference you linked does not say that is how `std::set::empty()` is actually implemented.

Comment: He used `edgeSet` in the code which could be a set or implemented as a set.  The reference only mentions a possible implementation. Irrespective of the implementation, the question the OP has asked is answered.

Comment: Thanks @P.W , this makes sense. I believe this also answers a follow-up question I would have had on whether `range_expression` would only be "called once" (yes) or "called for every loop" (no).

Comment: @juanchopanza , I see where you're coming from. I have a feeling for my purposes that avoiding the extra empty check will be fine, but I'll definitely keep in mind and research how expensive my iterators are when I come across them. Definitely a good catch, thanks.

Comment: @tjgrant This is the kind of thing that needs to be profiled. I agree with the conclusion that you most likely don't need this extra check. Except if data shows you that you do...

Comment: @P.W -- the C++ standard often describes requirements in terms of code. It also explicitly says "Such code is intended as a specification of equivalence of a construct to another construct, not necessarily as the way the construct must be implemented." [structure.requirements]/6. That is, `empty()` is not required to be implemented as `begin() == end()`. The requirement is that it must give the same answer.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Hard to disagree with someone who has implemented STL. :)